How to fix vimwiki auto hiding things when the cursor is not at that line?
I am new to Vim/Neovim and I'm facing a problem.
I need a very simple setup of vimwiki where I can link mathematica .m files together. No other bells and whistles required right now. I have everything setup but for some reason, for .m files, vimwiki is rendering any text of the form ^text here^ to text here when the cursor is not at that line. That is, double ^ in the same line are disappearing
My question is: WHY? Why does vanilla vimwiki have to hide stuff like this? Why cannot the vanilla setup give you a simple text editor?
This is driving me crazy because I want a simple Neovim setup where files can be linked together.
Technical Details:
Here is the content of my init.vim file, if this helps
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
call plug#end()

" Vimwiki settings
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/path/to/the/wiki', 'syntax': 'default', 'ext': '.m'} ]

Also, I am using Neovim v 0.10.0, if it helps.
What I tried:

In the init.vim file, I tried replacing syntax to 'markdown' and 'media'. Does not help.
I tried seeking help from chatgpt (which is what helped a noob like me set up the whole thing), but did not help.


At the moment when you install a plugin you have very much a non-vanilla setup. If you want vanilla, if you want plain and simple or it you're a new user and want to learn the basics: throw that plugin out and start over with a real vanilla Vim.

@Friedrich Thanks for the advice. I agree with you, and usually stick with the very basics in the beginning of anything. But in this case, I do need Vimwiki's basic ability to link text files like a wikipedia. VivianDeSmedt's response solved my issue.

You can ask Neovim to hide the concealed text by running the command:
set conceallevel=0

vim-wiki hide (conceal) the special characters that induces formatting to the text like _ for italic or * for bold or ^ for super script.
You can decide to reveal the concealed text or not using the conceallevel option.
More information with :help 'conceallevel'
If you want to have that automatically done for you for the vimwiki filetype you can add the following line to your init.vim file:
let g:vimwiki_conceallevel=0

More information with :help g:vimwiki_conceallevel.

Perhaps "reveal the concealed text"? It's already hidden

Thanks. This fixed my problem. Chatgpt was giving a similar command for init.vim, that was not working let g:vimwiki_syntax_conceal = 0.

Thanks for the feedback! Welcome to Vim :-)
